# Detect support for background-size: cover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is a save way to detect support for CSS3 *background-size: cover*, especially in IE < 9?

Following test returns a false positive in IE < 9, because it actually sets *background-size* to *cover*:

```
div.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
```

The only true result I get when testing for:

```
if ('backgroundSize' in div.style)
```

But according to the site http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/#bg11, IE 6/7/8 should return *auto*, only *cover* and *contain* are not supported.

**Edit:**

I would like to use my own solution, but I have checked the [code used by Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css-backgroundsizecover.js).
It seems they use the same technique that gives me false positive results in IE < 9:
Set *backgroundSize = 'cover'* and then check for *style.backgroundSize == 'cover'*.

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cx6DP/1/).

Answer (score 6):

If you use `Modernizr` you can download only the code necessary to perform this kind of task

http://modernizr.com/download/#-backgroundsize-testprop-testallprops-domprefixes

then you can test with

```
if (Modernizr.backgroundsize) {
    /* backgroundSize supported */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio. I would like to use my own solution, but have checked their code: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css-backgroundsizecover.js
It looks like they use similar code that gives me the false positive: set the style and then check for style.backgroundSize == 'cover'.

Comment: @JohnB. this appears to be their test for `cover` https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/backgroundsizecover.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to detect low functioning browsers to avoid having a postage stamp image stuck in the middle of things, then one quick and dirty workaround is to

```
var rules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
```

If it's undefined, then you know you have a low functioning browser and should probably go with your fallback approach. YMMV.

Comment: This is bad advice. The presence of one API does not determine the presence of another API. It is best to use proper feature detection by testing for the available properties. This is entirely possible without making strange assumptions about two unrelated APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if BackgroundSize exists as a style property before you set it.

```
var supported = ('backgroundSize' in document.documentElement.style);
if(supported){
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
    supported = temp.style.backgroundSize == 'cover';
};
return supported;
```

Source: http://upshots.org/javascript/javascript-detect-support-for-background-size-cover

Before this you might also want to try detection with CSS.supports().
see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports

Answer (score -2):

This is with javascript alone, no jquery just check the version of browser you delealing with

```
//check if Is bad IE. 
var noBGSizeSupport = window.attachEvent && !window.addEventListener 

if(noBGSizeSupport){
    //does not support BG size property
} else {
  // supports background size property
}
```