# Method to check for css background-size support

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a site that primarily uses the `background-size:cover` property for the background. However I'd like to support IE 7/8, I'm aware I could use IE conditional comments but checking for the property support would be more useful since it could support other old browsers as oppose to just IE.

I have the solution to the background issue, but I need to know when to add it with js depending on if there's support for the `background-size` property.

My question is, whats the best method to check for css `background-size` property in old browsers?

I have seen a few related questions but they all require using Modernizer, I'd prefer not using an extra library unless its the only option.

Thanks.

Comment: "checking for the property support would be more useful since it could support other old browsers as oppose to just IE" You are a great person.

Comment: Here is a very useful site that I use that tells me what works in what browser: http://caniuse.com/ . It makes a wonderful training tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if( 'backgroundSize' in document.documentElement.style)` would be the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: What about vendor prefixes? I doubt this covers all/many cases

Comment: @Ian The only vendor prefix here was `-moz-background-size`, and that was only around for Firefox 3.6. I don't think it's needed here.

Comment: I don't know, the MDN docs shows several prefixes for **older browsers** (which the OP asks for): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size , as well as a special way to use `filter` for IE 8

Comment: @Ian That may be, but in a case like this it's up to the OP to decide if it's worth testing for all the prefixes as well, or to just implement a fallback for browsers that don't support the unprefixed version.

Comment: Find a note here about this NOT working for Safari and iPad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244598/detect-support-for-background-size-cover#comment32076537_16419094

Comment: @lan also add -webkit for old versions of chrome and safari

Comment: @MahdiJazini If people are too lazy to update their browsers, then I'm too lazy to cater to them. Especially since all browsers have some kind of auto-update that you have to deliberately go out of your way to ignore/disable.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol 2 days ago i have checked my weblog visitors. did you know what i have seen there? Firefox was on top... did you know what browser was the 2nd in top? Internet Explorer 7. Also there was 1 visitor visited my weblog using IE6 and IE5 !!! i think maybe they are from old computers in offices or maybe a crawler... but i'm not sure :(

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol also check my post at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40916057/2758404